# How to add formula to Google Sheets URL parameters?

Tags: google-sheets, query-string, google-docs

Is there a URL parameter for a formula(fx) in Google Sheets?
[image]

These are all options/arguments:

```
    /copy
    /export
    /edit
    /preview
    /create
    /pub?
    /fm?id=
    /tq?tqx=out:html
    &key=[ID]
    &gid=[#]
    &single=[true|false]
    &range=[CellAddress|CellAddress1:CellAddress2]
    &embedded=[true|false]
    &widget=[true|false]
    &output=[html|txt|csv|pdf]
    &gridlines=[false]
    &rm=[minimal|embedded|full|demo|?]
    &ui=2 (interface version)
    &chrome=[false] (full screen mode)
    &width=[width]
    &height=[height]
    &frameborder=[size of border]
    &q=[Search Query]
    &viewer?
    &start=
    &channel=
    &ibd=
    &client=
    &fmcmd=12
    &size=0
    &fzr=[true]
    &portrait=[false]
    &fitw=[true]
    &printtitle=[true]
    &sheetnames=[true]
    &pagenum=[CENTER]
    &attachment=[true]
    &alt=[rss]
    &tq=[query params here]
```

I want to import csv into a spreadsheet using the command IMPORTDATA. And I would like to include this command in a link like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/create?formula=IMPORTDATA(%22https://example.com/data.csv%22)

Comment: add more details and drop that excel tag before excel dudes downvote you and close your question (again)

Comment: Can you provide more details on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to import csv into a spreadsheet using the command IMPORTDATA. And I would like to include this command in a link like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/create?formula=IMPORTDATA(%22https://example.com/data.csv%22)

Comment: After research, this seems to be infeasible. What would be your use case to check if other solutions might be better in this situation?

Comment: Hmmm, wish they provided some documentation on this. Never heard of &fmcmd, &start=, &ui, &fm?id, &ibd, &channel, &client, and would love to learn how to use it.